# The most elegant way to find n words in String with the particular word

Tags: python, regex, string

There is a big string and I need to find all substrings containing exactly N words (if it is possible).

For example:

```
big_string = "The most elegant way to find n words in String with the particular word"
N = 2
find_sub(big_string, 'find', N=2) # => ['way to find n words']
```

I've tried to solve it with regular expressions, but it happened to be more complex then I expect at first. Is there an elegant solution around I've just overlook?

**Upd**

By word we mean everything separated by \b

N parameter indicates how many words on each side of the 'find' should be

Comment: What does `'way to find n words'` have to do with `N = 2`?

Comment: Are you looking for particular substrings, or simply trying to determine the number of possible 2-word substrings in general? The latter calculation is relatively trivial.

Comment: What's a word in this context? Anything separated by a space?

Comment: @unutbu, N = 2 means that there should be 2 words on the left and on the right form the 'find' at the result

Comment: @Henry Gomersall,  Yes, anything separated by \d

Comment: @kmelnikov `\d` is a digit character.

Comment: @m.buettner, output shoud be ['way to find n words']

Comment: @m.buettner Ups, sorry. I mean \b :)

Comment: kmelnikov, instead of adding important information in the comments (like def. of word and def. of N=2 implying 2 words on each side of match-word) edit that information into the question.  A well-formed question gets upvotes; badly-formed questions get downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific example (if we use the "word" definition of regular expressions, i.e. anything containing letters, digits and underscores) the regex would look like this:

```
r'(?:\w+\W+){2}find(?:\W+\w+){2}'
```

`\w` matches one of said word characters. `\W` matches any other character. I think it's obvious where in the pattern your parameters go. You can use the pattern with [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) or [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

The issue is if there are less than the desired amount of words around your query (i.e. if it's too close to one end of the string). But you should be able to get away with:

```
r'(?:\w+\W+){0,2}find(?:\W+\w+){0,2}'
```

thanks to greediness of repetition. Note that in any case, if you want multiple results, *matches can never overlap*. So if you use the first pattern, you will only get the first match, if two occurrences of `find` are to close to each other, whereas in the second, you won't get `n` words before the second `find` (the ones that were already consumed will be missing). In particular, if two occurrences of `find` are closer together than `n` so that the second `find` will already be part of the first match, then you can't get the second match at all.

If you want to treat a word as anything that is not a white-space character, the approach looks similar:

```
r'(?:\S+\s+){0,2}find(?:\s+\S+){0,2}'
```

For anything else you will have to come up with the character classes yourself, I guess.

Comment: Thanks! It seems the problem is that I don't know re module properly :)

Comment: @kmelnikov are you saying you've figured it out now or that you need more guidance on how to use the pattern?